# How does one configure an Avaya 4524GT switch to work as an fibre to ether adapter?

Tags: networking, router, avaya

I have an Avaya 4524GT routing switch, which has some fibre ports and some ordinary ethernet ports. I want to internally bridge one particular ethernet port to one particular fibre port, so that the device effectively works as a fibre to ether adapter. How does one do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You connect both circuits, ensure that thy are linked up properly, then put them in the same VLAN.

Responding to your comment below, this is something that a **switch** does not do. It actually sounds like all you want is a media converter, which can be had for very cheap.

Comment: The question was how to do this. I want to tell the switch "unconditionally send everything that's coming in on wire 24 to wire 17, and vice versa".

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: It says it's a routing switch, so I thought this might be possible. I am rather new to all this. Yeah buying a media converter is a possibility too, but we were wondering if could use what we already have. Thanks, anyway!

Comment: You probably ought to do some reading up on basic networking. Routing, switching, and bridging (basically what the media converter does) are three very distinct technologies, with different use cases.

Comment: I agree, I really should. As a math guy I quite like to have a good conceptual understanding of what I'm working with (which I'm clearly lacking here) instead of just groping in the dark and tweaking configuration files till it appears to work. :-)

Comment: Cheers! (by the way, it's good etiquette to mark an answer as "accepted" at some point, if you're happy with the information provided.)